# Is there a way to pass the flutter Canvas object down to native code using FFI and have the native c code draw on the Canvas in a CustomPainter?

Tags: flutter, dart

We have this Charting library in java and objective-c. We are converting our whole native app over to flutter, everything else is easy to convert except this one task. The charting library has callbacks we implement and I can call a method up in dart to add this to a list of things that need to be drawn. But the charting library on iOS takes Core Graphics context and handles some of the drawing on its own to the View.

My Boss was hoping we could be able to have the charting engine in native land draw out some of the stuff on iOS and Android. But this seems like it is not possible without doing a PlatformView or UIKitView and having the native code do the work there.

Any suggestions what to do here, or is this even possible without a PlatformView or UIKitView and handling all this stuff down in native land?

Thanks!

We have it working with a PlatformView and UIKitView that flutter provides and the native code handles it. But we were hoping that we could call down into the native code and have all the drawing happing on a Flutter Canvas.